# PyFlink - How to readFile() with specified file input format (instead of text format)?

Tags: python, apache-flink

In Java/Scala API, there is a readFile(fileInputFormat, path, watchType, interval, pathFilter, typeInfo) method which reads files in the path based on the given fileInputFormat. With this method, I can read other file types, e.g. a gzip file.

Is there a corresponding method in Python API? (Or how can I read a gzip file with Python API?)

Thanks,
Acan

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the build-in python module gzip.

example:

```
import gzip
with gzip.open("test.txt.gz", "rb") as f:
    data = f.read()
print(data)
>>> b'example text'
```

here is a tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python-support-for-gzip-files-gzip

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `read_text_file` method of `stream_execution_environment` in PyFlink